# MySQLdb installation on Windows 7

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am running python 2.7 in windows 7. I'd like to link up to mysql and found MySQLdb. I have tried `easy_install mysql-python` and found the `/Z1` error. Although I downloaded the source, I'd like to avoid having to make all the changes to avoid the `Z1` error (due to the source expecting the VC compiler that i don't have). i downloaded the 1.2.4 binary and installed. however, when i start up python and try `"import MySQLdb`", it does not find it.

i have looked at many pages. i am sure that i am overlooking something obvious, but i am new to python and i've run around in circles at so many pages.

please help.

edit: the installation actually worked. the problem is that i must have installed a 32 bit version. it works fine in IDLE which is using python 2.7.3 32 bit. but i was trying to use ipython and spyder, both were set up as 64.

i tried to install  "unofficial version" from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ which i got from [Python: How to install mysqldb on windows 7 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284186/python-how-to-install-mysqldb-on-windows-7-x64). it claims python 2.7 is not in registry. any help here would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the /Z1 issue. However, i did determine what i did wrong with the binary install. i had included /python27/LIB/site-packages/MySQLdb only. once i also added /python27/LIB/site-packages/MySQL_python.1.2.4b4-py2.7.egg-info it worked. i did not verify whether i need both in the pythonpath or not. but having both does work.